# Spring MVC - REST what frontend technology should I choose?

Tags: spring, jsp, rest, velocity, freemarker

I would like to ask a short question. It is:
I want to create some web-application using Spring. I wanted to make RESTful webservice and handle it with HTML5 and jQuery but someone told me that it is stupid idea, wasting my time.

So I would like to know which technology is more used in: companies, by you, programmers in your private projects etc.
I have heard about:

- Freemarker
- Velocity
- JSP

And now I am wondering - should I return the view using some template engine from the list above or handle it with JS to present the data on the web and return just JSON from controllers? which way is the best approach?

I am going to create simple Spring, JPA etc. application and develope it by adding more utilities - just to learn java-web-developing for myself :)

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Who told you that it is a stupid idea :)?

Comment: @tonga someone, somewhere, cant remember :D however I thought about making 2 projects: first will take care about RESTful backend - database, counting, parsing data etc. and the second will be HTML5+CSS3+jQuery project which is going to consume the data that Spring REST returns and present it on the page, is it good idea? I have got now a little problems with integrating two projects and that made me think about the Freemarker etc.

Comment: These two technologies can be used to render the view. But it depends on your needs. If your client side is not just a web browser, then REST web service is the way to go. You can always use REST web service to reuse your server side code regardless of what client side is.

Comment: Yes, now I think that I understand it. I wanted to create RESTful WebService as a backend and it have to be view-technology-independent and return raw data in JSON. Then I will be able to implement my android/iphone app, web page, desktop app etc. even with another language. Thats my aim for now. So I think that using template-engines wont be good idea - I would have to return view name or strange objects like ModelAndView, and It would have been

Comment: really difficult (even impossible) to handle it with iPhone app or desktop app :)

However for someone who wants just web-page its good idea - template engines like Freemarker help manipulating java objects so it saves time. 

Am i right? Would you like to add something to instruct me?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a JSP.  You can still use HTML5 and JQuery within the jsp.  There are TONS of tutorials out there specific to Spring and JSP.
As to whether to use a returned view or js I would say try both.  It depends heavily on how you want your web-app to "act" If you are comfortable with page reloads and redirects... take the view approach.  If you prefer not to refresh the whole page, naturally JSON would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use server side templating, I would strongly urge you to take a look at [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/). It's got an awesome templating engine, is real easy to understand and it is being actively pushed by Spring ([Spring Boot](http://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) configures it automatically).

Answer (score -1):

JSP + Apache Tiles with Spring is a great option; Tiles is very easy to use (and to understand):

```
<definition name="myapp.homepage" template="/layouts/classic.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Tiles tutorial homepage" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/tiles/banner.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/tiles/common_menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/tiles/home_body.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/credits.jsp" />
</definition>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to use Tiles once, but I had big problem with integrating it with spring. There were some servlet-conflict (?) or something like that and I could not find solution :) But true, it seems to be quite easy and intuitive

Comment: First time I hear about a serious issue like that with Tiles, I've worked on several projects with exactly this combination of technologies... I'll keep an eye on it :) Hope you have luck in your research!